# Virtual switch with port mirroring

Tags: switch, mirror, lab

I have a lab in which I have three computers connected to a switch.
two of the switch's ports are mirrored to a third port so that all the communication between the two computers is mirrored to the third computer.

I would like to create a similar lab setup but with virtual machines.
I have no problem setting such virtual lab with only the computers (not the switch) (using vagrant and private network), but is there something I can use to replace the switch part.

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Open vSwitch](http://www.openvswitch.org/). It has many enterprise grade features, including port mirroring.

You will find on [this documentation page](http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/faq/configuration/?highlight=mirroring) the following information:

> Q: How do I configure a port as a SPAN port, that is, enable mirroring
>   of all traffic to that port?
>
> A. The following commands configure br0 with eth0 and tap0 as trunk ports. All traffic coming in or going out on eth0 or tap0 is
>   also mirrored to tap1; any traffic arriving on tap1 is dropped:
>
> ```
> $ ovs-vsctl add-br br0
> $ ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth0
> $ ovs-vsctl add-port br0 tap0
> $ ovs-vsctl add-port br0 tap1 \
>     -- --id=@p get port tap1 \
>     -- --id=@m create mirror name=m0 select-all=true output-port=@p \
>     -- set bridge br0 mirrors=@m
> ```
>
> To later disable mirroring, run:
>
> ```
> $ ovs-vsctl clear bridge br0 mirrors
> ```